# a question on riemann integration limits

Tags: integration, limits, riemann-sum

I think I have to use Riemann sum to solve the question below but i could not succeed. Thanks for your helpful hints or answers.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n^2}\cos\big(\frac{k}{n^2}\big)$$

Comment: the searched Limit is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Are you sure the argument of the cosine is what you wrote and *not* $\;\left(\frac kn\right)^2=\frac{k^2}{n^2}\;?$ Or perhaps just $\;\frac kn...?\;$

Comment: If the problem is correct as written, the answer is zero.

Answer (score 0):

As now you have changed the question the limit is now $$\int _0 ^1 x\cos (x) dx=\sin (1)+\cos (1) $$

Comment: The question is correct but i forgot to close the parantheses, sorry.

Comment: Don Antonio, You are right. I checked the question and see that i had to write cos(k/n) instead of cos( k/ n^2). So sorry...

Comment: In the question, there's still $\cos \frac{k}{n^2}$. @ötarcan, you should change that if it should have been $\cos \frac{k}{n}$.

Comment: Did you loose $dx$?